# how to position a UI Canvas at the same point as it's parent game object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a UI Canvas prefab which has an empty game object with the following script attached to it:

```c#
float remainderAngle;
Image rotAngleWedge;
Image remAngleWedge;

public Image rotateWedgePrefab;
float zRotation = 0f;

public void PieGraph    (float ringRotateAngle, Transform parentTransform)  {

    remainderAngle = 360f - ringRotateAngle;

    rotAngleWedge = Instantiate (rotateWedgePrefab) as Image;
    rotAngleWedge.transform.position = parentTransform.position;
    rotAngleWedge.transform.SetParent (transform, false);
    rotAngleWedge.color = Color.yellow;
    rotAngleWedge.fillAmount = ringRotateAngle / 360f;
    zRotation = Quaternion.Euler (parentTransform.eulerAngles).z - 45.0f;
    rotAngleWedge.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (new Vector3 (0, 0, zRotation));
    zRotation -= rotAngleWedge.fillAmount * 360f;


    remAngleWedge = Instantiate (rotateWedgePrefab) as Image;
    remAngleWedge.transform.position = parentTransform.position;
    remAngleWedge.transform.SetParent (transform, false);
    remAngleWedge.color = Color.white;
    remAngleWedge.fillAmount = remainderAngle / 360f;
    remAngleWedge.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (new Vector3 (0, 0, zRotation));

}
```

Then I called the `PieGraph` method in the parent game object script after creating the prefab using. I can't seem to get the UI Canvas to be positioned at the same place as its parent object. Please see images of the inspector settings for the Canvas and its child object below. How can I position them at the same place?

UI Canvas Prefab Inspector Settings
[image]

UI Canvas Prefab Child Game Object Inspector Settings
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to assign RenderMode to world space.

Comment: I changed it to World Space, but now the images (rotAngleWedge and remAngleWedge) are not appearing both in the scene view and game view

Comment: What you mean about? Can you select canvas game object in hierarchy? Can you find in on the scene? What about scale and position of all child hierarchy objects??

Comment: I can see them in the hierarchy but not in the scene or game view. When I select them in the hierarchy they seem to be positioned at the right place but they are not visible. Am I suppose to set an Event Camera for the Render Mode? If yes, how should it be setup?

Comment: Are you have some Image or text component in your canvas? Are you sure, the scale of all gameobjects are right? You don't need additional camera to see it in scene view.